# In clojure, how to write the identity function using the anonymous function literal?

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

How could one write the identity function in clojure using [anonymous function literal **(#())**](http://clojure.org/reader)?

The following code doesn't work:

```
(#(%) 5)
```

It raises an exception because it is converted to:

```
((fn[x] (x)) 5)
```

The problem in that when using **#()**, the function body is enveloped with parentheses.
Any idea, how to elegantly overcome this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, first of all, there is the `identity` function.

But you can use

```
#(do %)
```

if you insist.

Comment: Nice answer. If you know the parameter is a number, you can also do #(+ %) and save a character :-)